# How to disable CTRL-C during scp?

Tags: linux, bash

I want my script to be able to finish an `scp`, even if <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is entered. I have tried using a trap to disable <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, but it does not work when the `scp` is in progress. The `scp` terminates immediately. Is there any way to do this? Code is below. Pretty simple.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap '' SIGINT SIGTERM
scp -q user@server:/backup/large_file.txt /local/dir/
```

UPDATE: Also make sure you have "set -m" at the top of your script.

Comment: You could use `stty` to temporarily change the interrupt character to something other than control-C.

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put it in the background in a subshell to disconnect it from the terminal.

(scp ... &)

EDIT: You'll probably want to redirect any errors to a file.

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to disable the key interrupt completely until the transfer is done:

```
#!/bin/bash
STTY=$(stty -g)                        # Save settings
stty intr undef                        # Disable interrupt
echo -n "Press ENTER to continue: "    # Do your file transfer here
read response
stty ${STTY}                           # Restore settings
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it to background and be able to get the process in foreground again use this:

```
$ ( sleep 10 ; echo hello ) &
[1] 1323
$ jobs
[1]  + running    ( sleep 10; echo hello; )
$ kill %1
$
[1]  + 1323 terminated  ( sleep 10; echo hello; )
$ $
$ ( sleep 10 ; echo hello ) &
[1] 1325
$ jobs
[1]  + running    ( sleep 10; echo hello; )
$ fg %1
[1]  + 1325 running    ( sleep 10; echo hello; )
^C
$
```

So you can send the progress in the background with `&` and see all background tasks with `jobs` and you can access it with `%1` and kill it with `kill` and get it to the foreground with `fg`.